# Golang - Why this error happened in ServeHTTP Function : reflect: call of reflect.Value.Call on zero Value

Tags: go

My code and error message are in here: https://gist.github.com/WithGJR/a700e5d5bd35b5c8eef2

Could anyone explain for me why this error occured and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `value.MethodByName(info.controllerMethodName)` probably returns an invalid method, you should check `method.IsValid()`.

When something like this happens you start adding a bunch of `log.Println`s to see what's happening, well until a proper debugger is introduced.

//edit

```
router.Get("/", controllers.IndexController{}, "Index")
```

You're passing a value, `func (this *IndexController) Index()` is defined on the pointer so your `MethodByName` isn't working right, change your `router.Get` to :

```
router.Get("/", &controllers.IndexController{}, "Index")
```